# How to get these mod-rewrites to work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a 2 fold problem with doing 301 redirect. The old CMS I had on the domain is not being used and I am trying to figure out how to properly redirect if something matches.

1) Remove the query strings from the url and do a redirect. 
Here are the urls search engines trying to access which should redirect to the main page index.php

> Example: http://www.mysite.com/?dispatch=products.search&features_hash=P2
>
> Target: http://www.mysite.com/

OR

> Example: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?dispatch=products.search&features_hash=V9
>
> Target: http://www.mysite.com/

OR

> Example: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?dispatch=news.list
>
> Target: http://www.mysite.com/

Here is the code I tried so far which doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dispatch$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

2) The other problem I have is for some reason my site has duplicates in search engines via url= parameter. For example,

> Example: http://www.mysite.com/?url=http://www.mysite.com
>
> Target: http://www.mysite.com/

Basically they are same pages but when you take into account that I have category pages and other individual pages all being access by url= then its not right. Basically what I want to do is return 301 to the main mysite.com For this I tried the following code which doesn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

********------EDITED:------**********
Complete htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-p-([0-9]+).html$ my-pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|'|"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error_page.php [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

ErrorDocument 400 /error_page.php?error_id=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error_page.php?error_id=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error_page.php?error_id=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error_page.php?error_id=404
ErrorDocument 405 /error_page.php?error_id=405
ErrorDocument 408 /error_page.php?error_id=408
ErrorDocument 415 /error_page.php?error_id=415
ErrorDocument 500 /error_page.php?error_id=500
ErrorDocument 501 /error_page.php?error_id=501
ErrorDocument 502 /error_page.php?error_id=502
ErrorDocument 503 /error_page.php?error_id=503
ErrorDocument 505 /error_page.php?error_id=505
ErrorDocument 504 /error_page.php?error_id=504

<FilesMatch "\.(inc|tpl|h|ihtml|sql|ini|conf|class|bin|spd|theme|module|exe)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*" block_bad_bots
Deny from env=block_bad_bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tool25 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.txt [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.gif [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r57shell [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99 [OR]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Give some example URL and target urls.

Comment: @Zimbabao: Done. Added it as per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dispatch  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L] 


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php\?dispatch  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=http://www.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Zimbabo: First one creates a loop and throws an error. 2nd doesn't work. I copy pasted exactly as you posted. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: These are the only rewrites you have ? or you have added few more?, paste them if you have more

Comment: @Zimbabao: Done. I have posted the entire htaccess for your reference. Thanks again

Comment: Can you please enable rewrite logs, RewriteLog /path/to/logdir/rewritelog RewriteLogLevel 9  and see whats happening. I'm not able to get why its happening.

Comment: @Zimbabao: I can't get RewriteLog to work. I keep on getting 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Quote the log file. RewriteLog "/path/to/logdir/rewritelog" is the log file folder writable by apache users ??